# "step tens of millions of pounds"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning

What does it mean? I haven't found it even in Wiktionary. From [this](https://www.bbc.com/news/uk-politics-63334457) BBC article:

> The now not-so mini-budget sparked market turmoil, with the Bank of England having to **step** tens of billions of pounds to stabilise pension funds, and mortgage rates shot up.

Comment: It may be financial jargon. I've never come across it.

Comment: I haven't either.

Comment: This looks like an editing error.  It should be something like, "the Bank of England having to **step in**,* and provide* tens of millions of pounds."  I can't find any use of "step" except in the phrasal verb "step in".  So I think this is a mistake.  Is this worth writing into an answer?